# How to write a correct mongodb query for mongodump?

Tags: json, mongodb, mongodump

I'm trying to backup 3 articles from my database, I have their IDs but when I try to use mongodump I just can't seem to be able to write the proper json query. I get either a JSON error message, or some cryptic `cannot decode objectID into a slice` message.

Here's the command that I'm trying to run at the moment:

`mongodump -d 'data' -c 'articles' -q '{"$oid": "5fa0bd32f7d5870029c7d421" }'`

This is returning the `ObjectID into a slice` error, which I don't really understand. I also tried with ObjectId, like this:

`mongodump -d 'data' -c 'articles' -q '{"_id": ObjectId("5fa0bd32f7d5870029c7d421") }'`

But this one gives me a `invalid JSON` error.

I've tried all forms of escaping, escaping the double quotes, escaping the dollar, but nothing NOTHING seems to work. I'm desperate, and I hate mongodb. The closest I've been able to get to a working solution was this:

`mongodump -d 'nikkei' -c 'articles' -q '{"_id": "ObjectId(5fa0bd32f7d5870029c7d421)" }'`

And I say closest because this didn't fail, the command ran but it returned `done dumping data.articles (0 documents)` which means, if I understood correctly, that no articles were saved.

What would be the correct format for the query? I'm using mongodump version r4.2.2 by the way.

Comment: What is the operating system you are working in? Also, post a sample document.

Answer (score 2):

I have a collection with these 4 documents:

```
> db.test.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5fab80615397db06f00503c3") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5fab80635397db06f00503c4") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5fab80645397db06f00503c5") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5fab80645397db06f00503c6") }
```

I make the binary export using the `mongodump`. This is using MongoDB v4.2 on Windows OS.

```
>> mongodump --db=test --collection=test --query="{ \"_id\": { \"$eq\" : { \"$oid\": \"5fab80615397db06f00503c3\" } } }"
2020-11-11T11:42:13.705+0530    writing test.test to dump\test\test.bson
2020-11-11T11:42:13.737+0530    done dumping test.test (1 document)
```

Comment: an small tip I use is to enclose the query with single quotes (`'`) to avoid  escaping inner double quotes e.g. `'{"$eq": "something"}'`

Answer (score 0):

If your query is for JSON than try this format.

```
mongodump -d=nikkei -c=articles -q'{"_id": "ObjectId(5fa0bd32f7d5870029c7d421)" }'
```

Is there nothing else you could query though, like a title? Might make things a little more simple.

I pulled this from mongoDB docs. It was pretty far down the page but here is the link.

https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/mongodump/#usage-in-backup-strategy

Comment: No, that still doesn't work. The result is `done dumping nikkei.articles (0 documents)`, but I have checked the ID using mongodb compass and it indeed exists.

Unable to figure out the correct format I just used other fields that are not IDs, such as the article's title. I really hope I never have to work with mongoDB ever again.

Comment: This is not the way to go. `"ObjectId(5fa0bd32f7d5870029c7d421)"` will evaluate as a string and not an objectId. As suggested above, you should use the $oid approach

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer for those using Python:

Note: you must have mongo database tools installed on your system

```
import json
import os

# insert you query here
query = {"$oid": "5fa0bd32f7d5870029c7d421"}
# cast the query to a string
query = json.dumps(query)

# run the mongodump
command = f"mongodump --db my_database --collection my_collection --query '{query}'"
os.system(command)
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the `$oid` approach to resolve the issue with `ObjectId` type of field `_id` in my collection in the following way, and it worked:

```
mongodump --uri="mongodb://localhost:27017" --out="./collection_dump" --db=test_db --collection=test_collection --query='{ "_id": { "$in": [ {"$oid": "6440985904472b43c7cf6f55"}, {"$oid": "64392d624343a91020b71e14"} ] } }
```